# Unable to authenticate with the credentials provided

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am working wiht a commpany's data through Sharepoint. I have access the Sharepoint site with my gmail account. When I try to "Get Data" from Sharepoint into PowerBI Desktop and I log in the with the Gmail account that has access to the Sharepoint site I get "Cannot authenticate with the credentials provided."

I can download the data directly fromt he Sharepoint site but then when the company tries to open the PowerBI file it won't recognize the data source.

The data is in the form of an excel file inside of a folder.

I narrowed down to the level of the Sharepoint site that I have access to. I tried changing to my default browser.

Is there something that needs to be done on the company's end to enable me to get data from the Sharepoint site into my PowerBI desktop?
Is there an issue because i am using a Gmail account?

Is there another way to get/share data with the company that would be more effective and secure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.